# Uncaught TypeError: topFrame.window.changeSelectedBarStyle is not a function,why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my function changeSelectedBarStyle:

```
function changeSelectedBarStyle(tdId){
    $("#menuTable td").each(function(index){
        if(this.id == tdId){
            $(this).removeClass("menuPanel");
            $(this).addClass("menuPanelSelected");
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass("menuPanelSelected");
            $(this).addClass("menuPanel");
        }
    });
}
```

this is what i get from console:Uncaught TypeError: topFrame.window.changeSelectedBarStyle is not a function

and it turns a blank page.
but,this error only shows at the first time.if refresh the page,everything is all right.

----------------edit for more info---------------------

this is the function where call it,and i add some log(shows when the page is load correct not blank page this time):

```
    function changeTopFrameBarStyle(pageType){
        topFrame.window.changeSelectedBarStyle(pageType);
        console.log(pageType);//job(it is correct)
        console.log(topFrame.window.changeSelectedBarStyle);//changeSelectedBarStyle(tdId)
        console.log(topFrame.window.changeSelectedBarStyle(pageType));//undefined
        console.log(topFrame.window);//Window webSiteTopMenu.jsp(this page is the function changeSelectedBarStyle exists)
    }
```

and this it is the page that call the below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    window.parent.changeTopFrameBarStyle("job");
```

}

it is the matter with:
$(document).ready(function()

because before this happen ,it is using this:

```
window.onload= function(){
    window.parent.changeTopFrameBarStyle("people");
};
```

Comment: Where is the code that is calling this function? And what scope is it located in

Comment: I add some content to this question to rich the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that `topFrame.window.changeSelectedBarStyle` is *undefined*.  `console.log(...)` it to verify.

**It might be that the contents of the frame have not loaded yet**. Access `topFrame` on the `window.onload` event, which ensures that the DOM, all images, scripts, and frames are loaded.

Note that jQuery's `ready` event is fired after only the DOM is loaded, and so the frame content won't have been loaded at the time.

**If you are trying to access the `window` object of an `iframe`** you might be looking for the `contentWindow` property instead.

Comment: Can you explain what `topFrame` is referring to?  How is it being defined and set?

Comment: it is the top menu.like a navigation banner on the top of the page.I am not a front end coder.I am trying to edit some code in the page,not really know js..

Comment: as to my console-log,I think i might already get the topFrame.

Comment: <code>console.log(topFrame.window);//Window webSiteTopMenu.jsp(this page is the function changeSelectedBarStyle exists)</code>

Comment: Have you tried `topFrame.contentWindow.changeSelectedBarStyle()` as I suggested above already?

Comment: TypeError: topFrame.contentWindow is undefined

Comment: I change the code from **$(document).ready(function() {  
    window.parent.changeTopFrameBarStyle("job");  **to**window.onload= function(){
    window.parent.changeTopFrameBarStyle("people");
};**,it seems like works.but I donot know if there is some side effect if i make the `window.onload= function()` and `$(document).ready(function() ` in same page??????

Comment: `window.onload` is fired when *all* content on the page are loaded (images, frames, scripts).  JQuery's `$(document).ready` is fired when just the DOM is loaded (html elements tree), which is earlier.  This explains why this works for you, because the frame content is loaded after `window.onload`.  Just be aware that the code in your `.ready` will be executed before the code in your `.onload` block.  Good luck!

Comment: can you put the onload thing in your answer..I want to select your answer as the correct one,only to make sure it is complete.thank you for your explain about window.onload ,it is useful very much.